# Whoosh Filtering Raising AttributeError: 'Term' object has no attribute 'Term'

Tags: attributeerror, whoosh

I am trying to apply filter on whoosh results. When I apply filter without a python function, I get results. However, when I put filter in a python function, I get 'AttributeError: 'Term' object has no attribute 'Term'.
Please see the gist with example here: https://gist.github.com/akeahey/b6713a32cdff0ca2a58b63fdceab99be

Answer (score 0):

In this block of code:

```
def filtered():
    
    #search for term in individual
    with iy.searcher() as searcher:
        query = QueryParser("content", iy.schema).parse("example")
        allow_q = query.Term("ind_id", "123")
        results = searcher.search(query, filter=allow_q, limit=None)
        print(results, len(results))
```

Assigning the parsed query to the variable, `query`, masks your ability to create a `query.Term` object.

Please try this, instead:

```
def filtered():
    
    #search for term in individual
    with iy.searcher() as searcher:
        parsedq = QueryParser("content", iy.schema).parse("example")
        allow_q = query.Term("ind_id", "123")
        results = searcher.search(parsedq, filter=allow_q, limit=None)
        print(results, len(results))
```